# join two CSVs by IDs

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two CSV files like:

first.csv:

```
1,A B C
2,A D
3,T Q
```

second.csv:

```
1,
2,P A
3,
4,A O
```

Is is possible to join these two CSVs to make a CSV in similar format using pandas?

The output CSV should be like:

```
1,A B C
2,A D P
3,T Q
4,A O
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over each row of both of the CSVs and make a `set` of the combined lines:

```
import csv

with open('1.csv') as f1:
 with open('2.csv') as f2:
  with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:

   second_csv = csv.reader(f2.readlines())
   for first_row in csv.reader(f1.readlines()):
     second_row = second_csv.next()
     outfile.write(set(first_row+second_row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
first = pd.DataFrame('first.csv')
second = pd.DataFrame('second.csv')
third = pd.merge(first,second,  how='inner')
```

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is king for loading csv data in and manipulating it later.

Comment: you must have a vaild csv file. In your above example, the csv's are not valid and so wont be parsed correctly by pandas.  Is that the exact format that the files are in?

Comment: Specify the separator to be a space or comma, `sep=[',',' ']` in `read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that does what you want; it doesn't use Pandas, but it also doesn't assume the file rows are in any particular order.

```
import csv
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

def load_csv(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as inf:
        in_csv = csv.reader(inf)
        for row in in_csv:
            yield row

def write_csv(fname, rows):
    with open(fname, 'wb') as outf:
        csv.writer(outf).writerows(rows)

def main():
    # load data from several .csv files
    files = ['first.csv', 'second.csv']
    data = defaultdict(set)
    for key,items in chain(*(load_csv(f) for f in files)):
        data[key].update(items.split())

    # reorder data for output
    rows = ([key, ' '.join(sorted(data[key]))] for key in sorted(data.keys()))

    # write merged .csv file
    write_csv('output.csv', rows)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```